# Does SlackTextViewController interfere with the navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I'm using `SlackTextViewController` to present a chat room and for some reason I can't change the right bar button at all, in IB or programmatically. The cancel text is always there no matter if I add buttons to `navigationItem.rightBarButton`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had to connect my storyboard `UIBarButton` with IBOutlet to my custom class then set `self.navigationItem.rightBarButton = IBIcon`